# Run script using sudo with a get name inside returns root when using processes but doesnt for some other script that doesnt c#

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, sudo

So I have a script that is a master controller that has

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SUDO_USER")
```

which returns the sudo users username which it should this script is ran using sudo in a crontab which works fine however I have another script that is ran from this script using processes

```
 private static string RunCommand(string cmd)
 {
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "/usr/bin/sudo";
    psi.Arguments = cmd;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

    var process = Process.Start(psi);

    process.WaitForExit();

    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    return output;
}
```

However when this runs

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SUDO_USER")
```

it returns root which it shouldn't I have another script that does the same which is called the same way.

The weird thing is this was working yesterday but when I logon today it has done this and I have logged in with the same user and everything.

I have tried changing it to

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER")
```

but this only returns root on all scripts which is as expected

Comment: In addition if i run the command that the script run but outside of the script and just in terminal it works like it should only when it is ran from the script